# How to generate this chart kendo?

Tags: jquery, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

[image]

How can i generate this type of chart in kendo ? I tried to generate the chart with **"Kendo Radial Gauge"**.. but i am not getting what i expected

I tried with this data

```
     @(Html.Kendo().RadialGauge()
          .Name("gauge")
          .Pointers(pointers =>
          {
              pointers.Add().Value(10).Color("#c20000").Cap(c => c.Size(0.15));
              pointers.Add().Value(70).Color("#ff7a00").Cap(c => c.Size(0.1));
              pointers.Add().Value(140).Color("#ffc700");
          })
          .Scale(scale => scale
                 .MinorUnit(5)
                 .StartAngle(-30)
                 .EndAngle(210)
                 .Max(180)
          )
)
```

**Output  from radial gauge**

[image]

Comment: taking the demo code and tweaking slightly is this what you are after: http://dojo.telerik.com/isEziG

Comment: @DavidShorthose this is the one i also give example code with you... from this radial gauge how can i achieve the functionality wat i asked....

Comment: well you will need to restyle the guage to your needs. There are demo's which show you restyling. As for adding additional labels this isn't possible I don't think. So you would need to use the drawing api to achieve the final solution.

Comment: since i am stuck with this re-style with this... can you suggest us how can i achieve it...

Comment: have you looked at this example. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/radial-gauge/car-dashboard this shows you a fairly extensive demo of the restyling.

Comment: http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/wJOGgR

Comment: @ezanker the thing was i need to show the label for the item... but radial gauge dont support it seems... how can i show label for each item

Comment: @PrasadRaja kendo gauge does not support displaying the needle values, you'd have to do that yourself with HTML + javascript

Comment: @philr can you guide me to displaying the labels